# Powershell | Select-String multiple lines regex pattern filters nothing

Tags: regex, powershell, multiline, select-string, powershell-5.1

### The situation

I have a string like this:

```
some-text <!--
    <div class="">

    </div> --> some-other-text
```

From which I want to get only what's commented, so like this:

```
<!--
    <div class="">

    </div> -->
```

### What I've tried

I read similar questions, and the `Select-String` documentation multiple times, but I still can't understand what's wrong.

This is what I wrote:

```
# $Lines contains the string to be "cleaned"

$Cleaned = Select-String -inputObject $Lines -pattern '<!--(\n?.*?\n?)*?-->'
```

But if I print `$Cleaned` it's the **same string** as before the `Select-String`

I tested the regex on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it works.

I even tried to substitute the regex with a simple word like `div`, but nothing changed, still the same string.

### The question

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without Select-String: `$Cleaned = ([regex]'(?s)(<!--.*?-->)').Match($lines).Groups[1].Value`

Comment: It must be `'(?s)<!--.*?-->'`. Make sure the `$Lines` is a *string*, not an array.

Comment: The @Theo solution works. But I would like to know what's wrong with my `Select-String` statement.

The @WiktorStribiżew solution doesn't work. I confirm `$Lines` is a string.

Comment: Your input "string" `$Lines` propably is an _array_ of strings. `Select-String` matches lines individually, when passed an array. To match accross multiple lines, `-join` the array beforehand or make sure you already read the file as a single string, e. g. `Get-Content file.xml -Raw | Select-String ...`.

Comment: @zett42's comment explains the problem; the linked duplicate has a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @zett42 Doesn't `$Lines = $Lines.ToString()` make it a single string? Because I did that.

Comment: @Bit Have you tried to output `$Lines` to the console to see what it actually contains? Arrays don't have a useful `.ToString()` implementation, you will only get the type name (e. g. "System.Object[]").